# Migration to WordPress - first steps

Tags: wordpress, migration

I would like to migrate a html website into WordPress. At the moment I am not too familiar with WP but I've read that it is easy to use on the CMS side. (Also as a note I only have basic programming skills in html and css)

The website I would like to migrate is quite small, mostly static pages with 2-3 pages that are consistently updated for events and news articles (looks like in-line blog updates).

For the most part I would like to keep the theme of the website and then update with plugins as the website grows (i.e to include video and interactive content).

Could someone recommend the first steps to my conversion? I am currently reading Professional WordPress but migration isn't addressed until the end of the book and I would like to get the ball rolling (I have to because of my job).

Comment: Do you have any php knowledge?  Without it, things will be more difficult as it will be another thing you have to learn.

Comment: Unfortunately I have zero php knowledge. Since my last post I have installed WP as a sub domain and am now trying to make a theme so that I do not change the current website too much aesthetically. Any tips/recommendations on the best way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good overview video.  To get into specifics would really depend on what you're migrating from, so we'd need a little more detail.

Migrating A Massive Legacy CMS To WordPress Without Losing Your Mind:
http://vimeo.com/21118033

Comment: Thanks very much for the video. I am migrating from an html/css website that someone else built. They also built their own CMS for the site (which is very limited in what it can do, hence the switch). The website is currently live. I'm not entirely sure what other details to include - right now I have created a subdomain and installed wordpress there. I am currently trying to create a theme to duplicate the current design of the website as to not change it aesthetically. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thnx